# Golang creating dynamic functions (during run time)

Tags: http, web, network-programming, go, webdev.webserver

I need some help developing a web server in go.  I took initial code from http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/ , in particular, this example :

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This code is pretty simple to follow as all it does is redirect a get request going to "localhost" to the handler function which outputs html.

The problem I am having is that with my server I will be using javascript linkage in my pages (particularly JQ, and images, etc).  So when a GET request comes in for those artifacts I need to pull them from the drive as bytes and give them to the client browser in the handler (like above).

**However;  before run time I have no idea which files are located in local folders so I cannot pre-make these handlers.  I was wondering if go had a way to dynamically make functions during run time.**  So the psuedocode I'm thinking of would go something like this:

```
for file in files:
    http.HandleFunc(file.location, handler)
```

If maybe I'm going about this the wrong way and if anyone has ideas on creating handlers for these local files after reading them please let me know.  I also do not have any idea of the amount of files or how many but I can use Golang to read all the files.

Thanks!

Comment: if you just need to handle these file statically and are not doing any preprocessing on them, why not use `FileServer` as this exapmle shows? http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

as @Not_a_Golfer stated ; this can be done with FileServer for static files.  In my situation this works quite well as I have numerous unknown files.

Comment: This answer is downvoted because it's a top google result for golang dynamic functions but does not answer the original question.